# ImageView and Listview - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-imageview

Good Day!!!

I have a problem with the layout specially in the landscape orientation in android.

When I am going to change the orientation to landscape, it seems that the ImageView is in a fixed position and I can only see scrollbar in the listview...I just want to have a layout that also the imageview can be scrolled so that I can see clearly the list items.

Here's my layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/banner" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit tricky because you can't put a listview inside a scrollview but you can make it work if you create a custom adapter which can have different types of rows (e.g. A row with text only, a row with an ImageView, etc.).

Then have your first row in that ListView always be an image.

Check out this [tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) (Section: Different list items’ layouts) to learn how to make different types of rows.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample xml layout that suits my need

Comment: This cannot be done in the layout. You have to put your image inside the first row of the listview using a custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I think using ListView in ScrollView is not a good thing If u want that image should also scroll than do like this:

1) For Listview you need a custome **adapter**  in which in custom adapter class's **getview()** method u have to something like this

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View row;

    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_rowlayout, parent, false);

    TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_list);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.iv_list);

    textview.setText(data_text[position]);
    if(position==0){
    imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.YourimageName);
    }else{
     imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  return (row);

}
```

where your **listview_rowlayout.xml** is something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParenttop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:text="" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

and your **main.xml** in which u have added listview should be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment..and got some idea on how to solve it...with the help of the link benito gave.

I have created two xml layouts for row items in which a layout for my imageview and for my list item. I made the first item disable so that it can't be clicked.

Thanks for the idea anyways...